# Am I entitled to British ancestry through great grandparents?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, working

My mother's grandparents were both born in the UK and moved to the US as young adults.

Can my mother apply for some kind of working visa or dual citizenship, which can be passed along to me so that I am eligible to live and work in the UK?

Comment: The British ancestry visa is available only to commonwealth citizens.

Answer (score 3):

In general, British citizenship (or the equivalent status historically) can only be passed to one generation born abroad. Therefore, your mother would not have gotten British citizenship automatically, as she is in the second generation born abroad. Depending on her year of birth, it may have been possible to register your mother as a citizen as a child under certain conditions, but I am assuming that that never happened.

If your mother is a Commonwealth citizen, she may be able to get an ancestry visa to work in the UK.

Comment: How long has the one-generation limit been in effect?  Some people might have been born before it was put in place.

Comment: @phoog since 1948

Comment: @phoog: At least since 1915 (when the British Nationality and Status of Aliens Act 1914 came into effect); not sure about earlier. But from 1915 to 1982 it was possible to register a child in the second generation born abroad at a British consulate within 1 year of birth with the permission of the Secretary of State.